# Not receiving folders from Google Drive API using .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-drive-api

I am trying to add Google Drive support to a VB.Net program.  When using the Files.List() I am only getting files and not folders. I am using the V3 API and latest Google Drive .Net NuGet package. My understanding is that folders are just files so there should be nothing special to do.  I am not setting any query(Q).  I have DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, and DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata set as the scopes.  Here is the code for the File.List:

```
        request = GoogleDriveService.Files.List()
        request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime, trashed, parents)"
        Try
            files = request.Execute()
        Catch ex As Exception
            *snip*
            Return False
        End Try
```

I have 1 folder and two files on my google drive and the above only gives me the two files.

I also cannot get a folder by using Files.Get and the folders ID.  Using a file ID works fine.  Using a folder Id returns nothing.  Using the folder's ID on the API tester on the google developer site works fine.
Here is the code for the file get.

```
Dim getReq As FilesResource.GetRequest
getReq = GoogleDriveService.Files.Get(GoogleDriveFile.Id)
getReq.Fields = "id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime, trashed"
file = getReq.Execute()
```

I have tried everything I can think of and can't figure out why no folders.  This code is so simple.
Thanks,

Comment: I can't reproduce either part of this - listing files *does* include folders for me, and fetching a single folder works too. In your listing code though, you've only shown code to get the first page of results... perhaps the problem is that you need to use the `NextPageToken` from the response to fetch the next page of results (and keep going until there's no next page token)?

Comment: The NextPageToken is already null on the first call, so there is no next page.

Comment: That's a surprise, unless you have relatively few files. How many files and folders are in your Drive in total, and how many items do you get back in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can get files and folders together . Just pass folder name to function you will get fileid in return

```
Private Function getFileId(ByVal FileName As String) As String
            Try
                Dim service = GetGoogleAPPDriveService()

                Dim fileId As String = ""




                Dim lst_fileList = service.Files().List()

                lst_fileList.Fields = "files(id,name,parents)"

                Dim result = lst_fileList.Execute()

                If Not IsNothing(result) Then
                    For Each file As Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File In result.Files

                        'If file.Name.Contains("ba") Then
                        '    MsgBox("stop")
                        'End If

                        If file.Name.Trim = FileName Then
                            fileId = file.Id
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                Return fileId




            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Function

Private  Function GetGoogleAPPDriveService() As DriveService
            Try
                Dim Scopes1 As String() = {DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile}
                Dim ClientId As String = ""
                Dim ClientSecret As String = ""
                Dim UserCredentials As UserCredential

                Dim stream = New FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                ClientId = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets.ClientId

                Dim stream1 = New FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                ClientSecret = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream1).Secrets.ClientSecret

                Dim cs = New ClientSecrets()
                cs.ClientId = ClientId
                cs.ClientSecret = ClientSecret

                UserCredentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(cs, Scopes1, Environment.UserName,
                                                                             CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("MyAppsToken", True)).Result


                Dim service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
       .HttpClientInitializer = UserCredentials,
       .ApplicationName = ApplicationName})


                Return service


            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Function
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between your code and what I am doing.

Comment: I try your code now and it working fine for me .. Just check what count you get at ```  files = request.Execute() ```